# EF 7 Migrations with multiple DBContexts

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a problem scaffolding and doing migrations from a class library with multiple DBContexts.  I found a command line argument that looks like this for migrations:

```
dnx ef migration add -c Contexts.IndustryContext initial
```

But this doesn't even get by the command line parser.  I want all my DBContexts and database stuff out of the main MVC 6 web project and in their own DLLs.  Is this possible?  What command line magic is required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to this question and wanted to provide my solution for ef core 2.0.

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` needs to be added to each of your class libraries that have a `DbContext` in them. Right click the project and select `Edit *.csproj`. Then, add the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note: the version is the latest at the time of this post and will likely change in the future.

Next, I created a new Console App (.NET Core) called Migrations.Console and added it to my Solution. You will have to reference all of your `DbContext` class libraries in this project.

I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` Nuget packages.

In the `Migrations.Console` app, I created a DbContextFactory class for each Db context I have.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(local);Database=DATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Note: Make sure you update the context and connection string to match your project.

Now that each `DbContextFactory` is created, you can start to create the migrations. Go to the folder for your class library. The easiest way it to right click the project and `Open Folder in File Explorer`. Then, type `cmd` in the address bar of the `File Explorer` to open a command prompt in that folder.

Now use the following command to create the migration:

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -c ApplicationDbContext --startup-project ../Migrations.Console/Migrations.Console.csproj`

Note: Change `ApplicationDbContext` to match the name of the context you are working with. Also, if you called the console project by another name, you will need to change the path and name.

You should now see a `Migrations` folder in your class library.

Comment: Newly released instructions for updating tooling references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#update-net-core-cli-tools

Comment: @Todd Skeleton, thanks for the few tips: #1 using separate db context factory per db context class & #2 invoking command prompt from the address bar (atleast this is the first time I'm learning this trick).

Comment: However, i have a question, could you please clarify why you supplied the migrations.console project for the --startup-project option.? Also if you could please, clarify what does the --project and --startup-project options signify.?

Comment: The `--startup-project` cannot be a class library. It has to be project that you can actually run. This is the project the `ef migration` tool uses to connect to the database. The `--project` option is the actual project that you want the migration output to be added to--in this case--your class library.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried putting the data-layer in a separate project yet, but I do have multiple DbContexts in a single Web API project. It should work with separate projects too.

Using the latest syntax (v1.0.0), you create your migrations like this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add <migration-name> -o <output-directory> -c <context>
```

Where `<context>` is the full class-name of your DbContext -- like `MyProject.Data.MyDbContext`

I put my migrations for different contexts into different directories, but I don't think you have to.  Just make sure they have different `migration-name` values.

Answer (score 2):

The newest version (RC1 update 1) of the command line tools supports the following syntax:

```
Usage: dnx ef dbcontext scaffold [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
  [connection]  The connection string of the database
  [provider]    The provider to use. For example, EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer

Options:
  -a|--data-annotations                 Use DataAnnotation attributes to configure the model where possible. If omitted, the output code will use only the fluent API.
  -c|--context <name>                   Name of the generated DbContext class.
  -o|--output-dir <path>                Directory of the project where the classes should be output. If omitted, the top-level project directory is used.
  -s|--schema <schema_name.table_name>  Selects a schema for which to generate classes.
  -t|--table <schema_name.table_name>   Selects a table for which to generate classes.
  -p|--target-project <project>         The project to scaffold the model into. If omitted, the current project is used.
  -e|--environment <environment>        The environment to use. If omitted, "Development" is used.
  -v|--verbose                          Show verbose output
  -?|-h|--help                          Show help information
```