# ABP Update-Database error - The specified framework version '2.1' could not be parsed -

Tags: .net-core, aspnetboilerplate, package-manager-console

Just trying to create the database as part of the steps in [this](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Core) documentation.

Solution builds fine.

Message from Package Manager Console:

> PM> Update-Database
>
> The specified framework version '2.1' could not be parsed
>
> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1' was not
>   found.
>
> - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>       C:\Program Files\dotnet\
> - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
>       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
> - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
>       https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
> - The following versions are installed:
>       1.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>       1.1.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>       2.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>       2.0.6 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>       2.0.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>       2.1.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

[error copied from my VS window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyoI1.png)

Seems odd given that I have 2.1.5 installed.  Can someone with ABP experience point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't add Entity Framework Core migrations to .NET Standard 2.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789969/cant-add-entity-framework-core-migrations-to-net-standard-2-0-project)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have since abandoned ABP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an abp problem, but VS and dotnet core framework.

Scenario 1:

> 4. steps to follow
> 5. Update VisualStudio
> 6. Delete .vs folder
> 7. Restart PC
> 8. Run VisualStudio as administrator

This is what helped me.

Scenario 2:

> Write `PM> ls` and check if the VS package manager is a corect dir, If
>   not `cd folder` and try again. If not working go to Scenario 1.

Scenario 3:

> Copy your whole repository to C:/repo folder and try again.

**If all of those wont work reinstall .NET core 2.1 framework.**