# EF Core class library and migrations in azure pipeline

Tags: entity-framework, migration, azure-pipelines

I know that to use EF Core in a class library a startup project is needed, as explained here: [Is EF Core Add Migration Supported from .NET Standard Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430963/is-ef-core-add-migration-supported-from-net-standard-library)
However, I've managed to use `dotnet ef migrations bundle` **locally** using a single class library project (without using a startup project) by

1. Adding a ConfigurationBuilder you dbcontext
2. Overriding the "OnConfiguring" method to use the ConfigurationBuilder for reading the connection string where you have it. In my case from user secrets

```
    public partial class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        //will take the connection string from user secrets
        public MyContext()
        {
            this.configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddUserSecrets<ClpQUkMiContext>()
                .Build();
        }

        public MyContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                var connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStringInUserSecret"]
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }
        }
```

However, when I'm trying to use it in azure pipeline it's failing to find the connection string, which I have stored in a secret variable.
So far I've tried

1. Adding `".AddEnvironmentVariables()"` to the configuration builder.
2. Mapping the secret variable in the yaml file, like

```
variables:
 MyConnectionString: $(MySecreatConnectionString) # Setting variable to be read by the context
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue: To map a secret variable into an environment one that can be read by the configuration, it must be done **inside each** task, as crlearly explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

[dev variable inside the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tZLI.png)