# Cannot add EntityFrameworkCore Tools 1.0.1 to class library in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I am using the latest  VS2017 update with  donet core 1 I try to create an ef migration to my project
with the command `dotnet ef`
but I get

```
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

I then remove any reference to EntityFrameworkCore it from my Class Library csproj (.Net Core) and wanted to add the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.1 . However I refuses and I get the following error

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Package
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.1' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project
>   'MyVS2017Project'. 0 I also tried it in a Class Library (.Net
>   Framework)

Same error message when using the Package Manager Console command

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet

I tried editing the csproj file directly and adding

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference 
     Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" 
     Version="1.0.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

but dotnet ef still gives the same error message and nuget package manager doesn't see it

I tried to create a new dot net core class library but even a blank one refuses to install the tools

I have run dotnet restore multiple times and restarted visual studio.

I have downloaded the latest dot net SDK 1.0.4 and run repair to reinstall it. This allows nuget package to install  but despite but whatever I do I cannot get the class library to understand `dotnet ef`

Comment: After editing the csproj did you run a dotnet restore?

Comment: Yes I did do dotnet  restore

Comment: That package only works with console applications, it does not work with class libraries. Have you tried doing it in a console app? ...or in an asp.net core app, since it is also a console app.

Comment: I have always used class libraries with this app. Only since I upgraded to the last Visual Studio update has the whole thing broken. I need to use a class library as I separate my data layer/repository from my front end using class libraries

Comment: You can have your data layer in a class library, but you cannot run dotnet ef in a class library. See this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5320. As a test I really would create a console application, move the migrations there and run dotnet ef from there... just to test if that works. If it doesn't then you have a broken setup, if it does, then you are affected by this 'class library limitation'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My project targets the full .NET framework, so I can only use the PowerShell commands e.g. add-migration, update-database and not the dotnet ef commands

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` needs to be added to you class library by editing the project. That is the only way adding it is supported right now. Right click the project and select `Edit *.csproj`. Then, add the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note: the version is the latest at the time of this post and will likely change in the future.

I have a more in-depth solution here: [EF 7 Migrations with multiple DBContexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034589/ef-7-migrations-with-multiple-dbcontexts/45088343#45088343)